How do I remove locking garden hose?
I have this attachment on a garden hose which is preventing removal from the spigot. It appears to be push-button, but I can't get it to work. I had discovered a contractor had previously succeeded in unattatching it while working, only to find a subsequent contractor reattached it, so it's not broken, but I'm back to square one.
I did a web search, but couldn't find the item starting with an image search to lead to a how-to. Help.


Never heard of locking, but have used and seen quick attached.  You usually just wrap your fingers/hand around it and push one way or the other towards the hose/spigot.  They usually just turn off also.

I say it's locking simply because it won't turn on the spigot. Having image-searched 'quick attach garden hose accessory,' I still don't see what I've got or largely similar thing, but I'll try as crip659 says, pushing the whole thing, this weekend. If that doesn't do it, I have a hacksaw. Didn't an 'Upload Image' button used to appear underneath the typing field? That and words seem "fairly classic."
